# Event binding with views and AJAX-loaded collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm starting out with Backbone.JS, and have a question about how this should work.

I have a page which should load a list of sports, and then render the view. Now, because the list of sports is loaded via AJAX, I need to bind events to the collection so that it's only rendered when the data from that collection is actually loaded.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="../../src/vendor/zepto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../../src/vendor/underscore.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../../src/vendor/backbone.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sportsList"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="sports-template">
      <ul>
        <% _.each(sports, function(sport){ %>
        <li>
          <%= sport.getDescription() %>
        </li>
        <% }); %>
      </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="application.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As for the javascript code:

```
var Sport = Backbone.Model.extend({

  getDescription: function() {
    return this.get('description');
  }
});

var Sports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Sport,
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.bind("refresh", function() {
      options.view.render();
    });

    var sports = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/?service=ListSportsService&callback=?',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        sports.refresh(data);
      }
    });
  }
});

var SportsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#sportsList',
  template: _.template($('#sports-template').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    this.model = new Sports({view: this});
  },
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({sports: this.model.models}));
    return this;
  }
});

var SportsController = Backbone.Controller.extend({
  routes: {
    'sports': 'listSports'
  },

  listSports: function() {
    new SportsView();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  window.app = new SportsController();
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

The part that really nags me is having to pass the view to the collection and binding the refresh event there so that I can render the view once everything is loaded.

My question is, is there a DRYer/simpler way of doing this that I'm missing?

Keep in mind I'm using ZeptoJS instead of jQuery.

Comment: You pass the collection to the view, not the other way around.  Set up the view, then add stuff to the collection, then it all works!

Comment: Care to back that up with a proper answer and a code sample? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your collection should read

```
var Sports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Sport,
  url: '/?service=ListSportsService&callback=?'
});
```

Always use Backbone.sync functionality when possible (here by specifying the url on the collection and using fetch).

Your controller should read

```
var SportsController = Backbone.Controller.extend({
  routes: {
    'sports': 'listSports'
  },

  listSports: function() {
    //create the view with the collection as a model
    this.sports = new Sports();
    this.view = new SportsView({model: this.sports});
    this.sports.bind("refresh", this.view.render);

    // fetch all the sports
    this.sports.fetch();
  }
});
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Does not work as "this" inside SportsView.render() is the model, not the view.

Comment: Not following you... "this" in the render is your view. (side note you have to remove the initialize function in your view)

Comment: It binds the event handler to the render function, and that is correct, but the problem here is that inside render(), "this" is the sports collection, not the view object.

Comment: Well you need to bind this properly. In your view initialize function add this: _.bindAll(this, "render")

Comment: Care to make a better suggestion, @rajkamal? I'm all up for getting things right!

Comment: @rajkamal, I think you are missing how backbone works with collections. The actual ajax call happens with the fetch call and the binding prior to that will react to the successful completion of that call.

Comment: @julien, @changelog thanks for pointing my mistake. From @julian, i got the below understanding. Please correct me if im wrong. Only on collection.fetch(), ajax will be triggered, till then it is just a collection instance we are assigning to this.sports( this.sports = new Sports();).When fetch completes successfully, refresh on collection will be triggered, which in turn will paint our collection view.. correct ? Thanks again for pointing my mistake.